# Selenium How to click

Tags: python, selenium

This is my source code :

```
  <a id="form_week:btn_before" title="Précedent" onclick="var cf = function(){disableLink('btn_before');};var oamSF = function(){return oamSubmitForm('form_week','form_week:btn_before');};return (cf()==false)? false : oamSF();" href="#">
```

How to click on that link ?

Edit:

I tested your three answers but

```
 mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Précedent"]').click()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

SOLVED:

It's my fault , I did not see that the element 'a' was in a iframe.

```
mydriver.switch_to_frame(mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"));
mydriver.find_element_by_id('form_week:btn_before').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do that:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('form_week:btn_before').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

**It will click on the element 'a' with title 'Précedent'**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Précedent"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the click command and pass the element ID

```
selenium.click("form_week:btn_before")
```

Answer (score 0):

Import `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions`, this will tell your driver to wait up to 60 seconds while trying to find the button. Then try to get it by using it's ID:

```
WebDriverWait(
    webdriver,
    60
).until(
    expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.ID, 'form_week:btn_before'))
).click()
```